# Items being added to ListView but aren't visible

Tags: c#, listview

I'm trying to add items to a ListView, and the ListView seems to populate. The scrollbar appears, but the headers disappear and the items are invisible. I don't understand what's going on.

When I try to populate the list one item at a time, the items show up. If I change the view to List, LargeIcon, SmallIcon, or Tile, the items all show up. For some reason though if I have the view set to Details the items don't appear, and the column headers disappear.

Here's the code...

```
private void RefreshUIForRecord()
    {
        string colRecFlagStr = "Recorded";
        lstFiles.Clear();
        int fileId;
        int round;
        string descript;
        int recFlag;
        DataRow dr = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < DtList.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            dr = DtList.Rows[i];
            fileId = Convert.ToInt32(dr.ItemArray[0]);
            round = Convert.ToInt32(dr.ItemArray[1]);
            descript = dr.ItemArray[2].ToString().Trim();
            recFlag = Convert.ToInt32(dr.ItemArray[4]);
            bool add = false;
            Color color = Color.Black;

            switch (recFlag)
            {
                case 1:
                    if (chkShowRecd.Checked)
                    {
                        add = true;
                        color = Color.Green;
                        colRecFlagStr = "Recorded";
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    if (chkShowDontRec.Checked)
                    {
                        add = true;
                        color = Color.Red;
                        colRecFlagStr = "Don't Record";
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    add = true;
                    break;
            }

            if (add)
            {
                ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();

                if (descript != "")
                    lvi.Text = descript;
                else
                    lvi.Text = (AmpScriptId.ToString("D3") + "scr" + fileId.ToString("D4") + VoiceID.ToString("D5") + round.ToString("D2") + ".wav");                    
                lvi.ForeColor = color;
                lvi.SubItems.Add(colRecFlagStr);
                lstFiles.Items.Add(lvi);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: A DataGridView would be gobs easier to populate esp if that `dtList` is a datatable.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem was this line here...

```
lstFiles.Clear();
```

I meant to just clear the items, but it was clearing the columns as well. I changed the line to this...

```
lstFiles.Items.Clear();
```

Now it works as intended.